# Я хочу что-бы оператор /n перенёс строку

Tags: javascript, get, this, alert, obj

```
let obj ={
  name:"Toha",
  post:"admin",
}

Object.defineProperty(obj, "naPost", {
  get (){
    return `Имя : ${this.name} Пост : ${this.post}`;
  },
});

alert(obj.naPost);
```

Результат должен быть таким:

Имя : Toha
Пост : admin

Comment: Добавьте хотя бы html + css.  решается это через их

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Слэш должен быть обратным, чтобы получить символ новой строки

```
return `Имя : ${this.name} \n Пост : ${this.post}`;
```

Comment: только без  css это не работает))), добавь что у блока с текстом должно быть свойство    white-space: pre-line;

Comment: Еще как работает,спасибо большое ,Василиса.

Comment: @VladislavLoza всегда пожалуйста :) Буду благодарна, если примете ответ

Comment: Еще одна минута и приму